# ValueError: 'DateFormatter found a value of x=0, which is an illegal date'

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I have lists of time in seconds. e.g.:

```
[0, 15, 30, .... 18615, 18630, 18645]
```

and I want to plot it as hour:min:sec against an equally long list of values.

I have tried using date formatter but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: DateFormatter found a value of x=0, which is an illegal date.  This usually occurs because you have not informed the axis that it is plotting dates, e.g., with ax.xaxis_date()
```

I have already implemented the `ax.xaxis_date()` so that shouldn't be the problem. Hope you can help me get the x-axis to show time in hours instead of seconds.
The relevant code:

```
self.samp_freq = 15             
self.noise_samp = np.arange(0, self.time_total, self.samp_freq)
self.random_noise = np.random.normal(0, 10, len(self.noise_samp))

self.noi_ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(5))
self.noi_ax.xaxis_date()
self.noi_ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))

self.noi_ax.plot(self.noise_samp, self.scaled_random_noise)[0]
self.noi_ax.set_xlabel('time (sec)')
self.noi_ax.set_ylabel('noise (uGal')
```

Comment: Should `xasis_date()` be `xaxis_date()`?

Comment: @Jon Skeet My bad. That is a typo in the question. I corrected it. code still shows the same error. The plot shows up but without axes.